# Create Procedure and permissions

Tags: sql, sql-server

One person has permission for table 1 - and two of her coworkers do not have permission to read it. If the person were to run a stored procedure that used data from table 1 with the create procedure statement would her coworkers be allowed to see that data?

I am assuming that they will not be allowed to see the data, but I'm not 100% sure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE testtest
WITH EXECUTE AS ....
```

Comment: If the second people had access to the stored proc, then yes. One of the primary benefits of a stored proc is you can control how people see the data without having access to the underlying tables.

Comment: Why don't you test it for yourself?